# keeping list view item highlighted until it is clicked once

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, adapter

I have a list view which I am updating with the messages, Just like android inbox messages I want to keep the list view item highlighted until it is opened or clicked once,My code for populating the list view is:

```
  List<Message> values = datasource.getAllMessages(ch);
        Collections.reverse(values);
        ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
       setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Function getAllMessages is getting the values from the database in order to populate the list,
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom adapter by extending the ArrayAdapter class to achieve that:

```
private class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
{
    public Adapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, String[] strings)
    {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, strings);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        .......
        //do the logic of highlighting each row

        return view
    }
```